# Calling google.script.run.withSuccessHandler multiple times

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I'm trying to run refreshPage() every minute in a google web app. Although I cannot seem to get the function to repeat. Does anyone see any issues? It runs correctly the first time.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(refreshPage(), 60000);
  });

  function refreshPage()
  {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(googlescript).myfunction();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is you call your function in set interval and then setInterval gets `undefined` as function. this is the solution (just remove parentheses in front of refreshPage in setInterval):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(refreshPage, 60000);
});

function refreshPage()
{
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(googlescript).myfunction();
}
```

If you want it to run once at the beginning then you can change you can use one of these suggestions:

```js
function refreshPage() {
  console.log('refresh page');
}
refreshPage();
setInterval(refreshPage, 1000);
```

or

```js
(function refreshPage() {
  console.log('refresh page');
  setTimeout(refreshPage, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

possible solution

```
setInterval(function(){ google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(googlescript).myfunction(); }, 6000);
```